# Django CMS Deleting HTML5 Tags and Attributes

Tags: django-cms

I am having a big time issue with solving a problem. I have a placeholder called main for the content region of the page. I was building that region in the cms. Everything was going great until I attempted to add an embedded video contained in an iframe. When I save django cms completely removed the iframe and left an empty div. So I attempted to use prettyphoto light box to open the video by clicking on an image. The code I added to the page through the cms is:

```
<a rel='prettyPhoto[youtube]' href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mqVZF_yb8C0?autoplay=1&start=1765&iframe=true" data-rel="prettyPhoto">Click Image</a>
```

When I saved, django cms completely removed the data-rel attribute from the link which is obviously needed for the js. So I went a step further and adapted the code of the data attribute to:

```
rel="prettyPhoto"
```

and the cms also removed that attribute! Also anytime I add an html5 tag like article of section it hates that too! What gives here? Am I doing something wrong? Any advice would be appreciated.

Aaron,
Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a specific plugin to add these snippets of code ?

Answer (score 1):

Please see the discussion at https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/1529. We use html5lib to clean the contents of the text plugin (this cannot be turned off for security reasons).

What you'll want to do is write a custom plugin (possibly one that can be embedded inside text plugins).